# Unknown syntax error involving greater than value

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, input, numbers

I do not know why there is a syntax error, this is so simple but keeps coming up wrong.

```
number = float(input("How much shall you be spending today?")             
 if number>10
  print("You get 20% off")
 else
  print("You get 10% off ")
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if/else` statement is indented, and shouldn't be. Additionally, you need `:` after the if/else statements, and a second `)` on the first line. Finally, you should be using `raw_input()` with Python 2.7. Your code block should look like this:

```
number = float(raw_input("How much shall you be spending today? "))         
if number > 10:
    print("You get 20% off")
else:
    print("You get 10% off")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first line, you said 'input' but the correct function was `raw_input`. Also, the indentation for your if statement is wrong which can cause problems.